# Wrong drawables are being displayed after I add new images to the folder

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-drawable, android-resources

Every time when I add a new *.png file to the *drawable-21* folder in my project, all images in my activities get mixed up (wrong images are displayed). I tried rebuilding, refreshing and cleaning my app. I also did "Invalidate cash and restart" thing. 
I've checked the integer references of drawables that I'm using to display them in my activity and the numbers are correct. But obviously, they lead to the wrong pictures.

Here's part of my code (in recycle adapter) where I populate images:

```
name.setText(operationalList.get(pos).getName());
imageView.setImageResource(operationalList.get(pos).getDrawable());
```

- operationalList is updated from the sql database

It feels like some sort of resources refresh is needed, but I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: Did you notify adapter after adding new image

Comment: Yes, I did, thank you